# Handling HTML onClick function on Webview. shouldOverrideUrlLoading() not called

Tags: android, html, kotlin, webview, android-webview

I want to intercept an 'onclick' function from an HTML page loaded into my WebView.

```
<div class='button' onclick="location.href='http://do_something';">
<span>
  Click Here
</span></div>
```

this is the click event on HTML page that I'm interested, but unfortunately my WebClient's 'shouldOverrideUrlLoading()' method not at all triggered for this click.

When I change the above HTML button like this(below) its work fine.

```
<a href="http://do_something">Click Here</a>
```

But I really don't want to make any changes to HTML. Any idea to handle this click event without modifying the HTML contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `onclick` attribute [executes JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp) (`location.href`), you need to enable JavaScript in your `WebView`:

```kotlin
val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
```

Note that this [should be used carefully](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips#WebView) as it can introduce XSS vulnerabilities into your application.